# How to save the tensorflow's word2vec in text/binary file for later use of kNN output?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, word2vec, embedding

I have trained a word2vec model in tensorflow. But when I save the session, it only outputted `model.ckpt.data` / `.index` / `.meta` files.

I was thinking of implementing KNN method in retrieving nearest words. I saw answers of using gensim, but how can I save my tensorflow word2vec model into `.txt` first?

Answer (score 0):

Simply evaluate the embeddings matrix into a numpy array and write it to the file along with resolved words. Sample code:

```py
vocabulary_size = 50000
embedding_size = 128

# Assume your word to index map
word_to_idx = { ... }
# Assume your embeddings variable
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],0,1))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  embeddings_val = sess.run(embeddings)
  with open('embeddings.txt', 'w') as file_:
    for i in range(vocabulary_size):
      embed = embeddings_val[i, :]
      word = word_to_idx[i]
      file_.write('%s %s\n' % (word, ' '.join(map(str, embed))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and tried Maxim's solution.

You need to replace the line:

```
word = word_to_idx[i]
```

with

```
word = idx_to_word[i]
```

You can simply reverse the word_to_idx-dictionary with the following code:

```
idx_to_word = dict(zip(word_to_idx.values(), word_to_idx.keys()))
```

Except for that, his solution works fine.