# Can I export the embedding matrix of words in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, nlp, deep-learning, word-embedding

```
def word_embedding(shape, dtype=tf.float32, name='word_embedding'):
  with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.variable_scope(name):
    return tf.get_variable('embedding', shape, dtype=dtype, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1), trainable=True,partitioner=tf.fixed_size_partitioner(20))
embedding = word_embedding([vocab_size, embed_size])
inputs_embedding = tf.contrib.layers.embedding_lookup_unique(embedding, inputs)
```

Here is my code and the `embedding` is the variable for word to look up their own embedding vector.

I have trained the embedding matrix and I want to extract it from the model saved. The model also contain other parameters for example the neural networks above embeddings. Can I implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47892839/712995) to a similar question.

The simplest way is to evaluate the embeddings matrix into a numpy array and write it to the file along with resolved words.

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
  embedding_val = sess.run(embedding)
  with open('embedding.txt', 'w') as file_:
    for i in range(vocabulary_size):
      embed = embedding_val[i, :]
      word = word_to_idx[i]
      file_.write('%s %s\n' % (word, ' '.join(map(str, embed))))
```

If you want to save the embeddings just for *this* graph, you can create `tf.train.Saver` and pass the list of variables to save:

```py
saver = tf.train.Saver([embedding])
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.save(sess, 'path/to/checkpoint')
```

Comment: Thanks. I have use your code and it is OK in singe machine mode. But it can not work in distribution mode. Could you please take a look at the error ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059248/could-not-satisfy-explicit-device-specification-bug-in-tensorflow